# Does -XX:+UseSerialGC use main thread for GC

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have been reading (for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html) and [here](https://javapapers.com/java/types-of-java-garbage-collectors/)) that with `-XX:+UseSerialGC` garbage collector only single thread is used for garbage collection. But it was not clear whether this "single thread" is the `main` thread or a different single GC thread.

So, I took a thread dump with and without `-XX:+UseSerialGC` and to me it looks like when this option is used then GC is performed by `main` thread because I do not see any GC threads (like `"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)"`) when I use `-XX:+UseSerialGC`.

Could somebody who has good experience and knowledge on JVM and GC please confirm or correct my understanding.

**Without `-XX:+UseSerialGC`:**

```
2018-03-15 17:52:36
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d88d800 nid=0x1e64 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d809000 nid=0x2598 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d806800 nid=0x30d8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d801800 nid=0x1338 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d800800 nid=0x306c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c18b800 nid=0x323c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001c16d000 nid=0x2dd0 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d7fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076f2011d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x000000076f2011d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c12b800 nid=0x28a8 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076f208178> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x000000076f208178> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000223d000 nid=0x3174 runnable [0x00000000026ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    - locked <0x000000076f2240c0> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    - locked <0x000000076f201258> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    - locked <0x000000076f201218> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    - locked <0x000000076f201258> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at com.learn.stackoverflow.general.memory.GCThreadCount.main(GCThreadCount.java:12)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c124000 nid=0x25e0 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002256000 nid=0x3198 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002257800 nid=0x1ed4 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002259000 nid=0x199c runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000225a800 nid=0x2870 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d8ad800 nid=0x1fa0 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 8


With 2018-03-15 17:52:36
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d88d800 nid=0x1e64 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d809000 nid=0x2598 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d806800 nid=0x30d8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d801800 nid=0x1338 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d800800 nid=0x306c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c18b800 nid=0x323c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001c16d000 nid=0x2dd0 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d7fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076f2011d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x000000076f2011d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c12b800 nid=0x28a8 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076f208178> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x000000076f208178> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000223d000 nid=0x3174 runnable [0x00000000026ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    - locked <0x000000076f2240c0> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    - locked <0x000000076f201258> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    - locked <0x000000076f201218> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    - locked <0x000000076f201258> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at com.learn.stackoverflow.general.memory.GCThreadCount.main(GCThreadCount.java:12)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c124000 nid=0x25e0 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002256000 nid=0x3198 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002257800 nid=0x1ed4 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002259000 nid=0x199c runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000225a800 nid=0x2870 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d8ad800 nid=0x1fa0 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 8
```

**With `-XX:+UseSerialGC`:**

```
2018-03-15 17:54:47
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001351a000 nid=0x2388 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013492000 nid=0x2630 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013490000 nid=0x3084 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001348b000 nid=0x32cc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013489800 nid=0x3334 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013488000 nid=0xcc0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000013469800 nid=0x3144 in Object.wait() [0x000000001380f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c5a60d18> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000006c5a60d18> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013422000 nid=0xf20 in Object.wait() [0x000000000259e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c5a60ed0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000006c5a60ed0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000022cd000 nid=0x332c runnable [0x000000000274f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    - locked <0x00000006c5a6e000> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    - locked <0x00000006c5a60f20> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    - locked <0x00000006c5a60ee0> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    - locked <0x00000006c5a60f20> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at com.learn.stackoverflow.general.memory.GCThreadCount.main(GCThreadCount.java:12)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000013419000 nid=0x13e8 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000014311000 nid=0x3364 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 8
```

Comment: The serial GC should run on a native VM thread - not on any Java thread.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez Thank you for your reply. Could you please elaborate. And how about parallel GC, for them also it is native threads?

Comment: There is one clue about this in the [*Java Performance Companion*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Performance-Companion-Charlie-Hunt/dp/0133796825/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1521119566&sr=8-1&keywords=java+performance+companion), page 2, chapter 1: *[...] In the case of the HotSpot garbage collectors, almost all multithreaded GC operations are handled by internal Java VM (JVM) threads. One major exception to this is the G1 garbage collector, in which some background GC work can be taken on by the application threads.*

Answer (score 2):

If serial GC is enabled, thread failed to allocate memory is used for executing garbage collection.

If you take mixed thread dump during such GC, you can observe JVM GC related code is being executed recursively from allocation attempt in Java code.

This is specific of single threaded GC algorithm. All variations of multithreaded GC are using dedicated thread pool of GC workers.

Comment: Would you have a reference about this for the serial GC? Is the thread allocating memory an application thread?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez why do you need a reference? If you need confirmation you could just take thread dumps *including native stacks* yourself, which is what Alexey suggested.

Comment: @the8472 because otherwise there would be no point in asking (or answering) anything in stackoverflow. In a way or another, everything can be ultimately emperically verified by the poster, avoiding posting the question. Would that be a better world? Doubtful.